# Preventing SQL Injection on ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, validation

I am new to C# and ASP.NET.

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005 and have done some research on preventing SQL injections

I have a couple of functions in my **server-side** web application which I am unsure if they requires input validation.

---

**1)**  **Login** control from the toolbox. I have implemented the login control directly from the VS Toolbox, and I tried to use a *RegularExpressionValidator* for my login tool but it does not seem to work. Does Microsoft already have a in-built validation for the tool?

---

**2)**  **Upload** of excel file sheets into SQL Server database. I have a function which allows users to upload excel file sheets into the database. At the beginning I don't feel that there is a need to validate it as there is no open sql queries, but after that I'm asking myself if it is possible for the user to input SQL queries in the excel file which will cause SQL injection during uploading. Below is my upload code snippet, would be looking forward to advice if a validation is required:

```
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strUploadFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

using (OleDbConnection connection =
             new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    string selectStmt = string.Format("Select [COLUMNS]  FROM [userlist$]");

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectStmt, connection);

    connection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");
    // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
    using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // SQL Server Connection String
        string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<datasource>";

        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                   new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserDB";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**3)**  **INSERT** statements. I have a couple of `INSERT` statements which is mainly used to insert new records into the database. As these statements do not actually grep data from the database, I am unsure if a validation is required. Below is a sample `INSERT` statement:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<datasource>");
string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO [UserData] (Username, Password, Role, Membership, DateOfReg) VALUES ('" + un.Text + "', '" + pw.Text + "', '" + role.Text + "', '" + ms.Text + "', '" + dor.Text + "')"); --> all *.Text are textboxes on the webpage

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

---

**4)**  **Search** function in webpage. I have several .aspx pages which displays data by GridView. Below is an example of my search query which uses a textbox and a dropdownlist filter:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [UserData] where [" + DropDownList1.Text + "] like '%" + searchTextBox.Text + "%'";
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

---

I would like to know what is the easiest way to do a input validation check on **the sql statements itself without creating additional methods and functions**, to the above examples, as I have seen `regular expression` and using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Thank you in advance for any advice and suggestions provided.

Direct examples given would be good as well.

Answer (score 11):

Validation (checking for things like quotes etc) is **never** required in these examples, and should never be used (except for a few cases, where white-listing might be appropriate).

What is required is *parameterisation*. Use parameters instead of concatenation.

SqlBulkCopy handles the data directly, so that is *fine*, however:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<datasource>");
string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO [UserData] (Username, Password, Role, Membership, DateOfReg) VALUES ('" + un.Text + "', '" + pw.Text + "', '" + role.Text + "', '" + ms.Text + "', '" + dor.Text + "')"); --> all *.Text are textboxes on the webpage

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

is just **asking** to be abused horribly. **YOUR SYSTEM IS BROKEN**. You should have something like:

```
cmd.CommantText = "INSERT INTO [UserData] (Username, ...) VALUES (@username, ...)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", un.Text);
...
```

or any of the other ways of adding parameters.

your example 4 is an interesting one, which is an example of where white-listing might be appropriate; SQL Server does not allow you to parameterise the column name, but you **cannot trust** the value coming up from the client. If you **need** that kind of "choose the column based on input", you must test it against the expected values:

```
string[] allowedColumns = new[] {"Name", "Description", "Foo", "Bar"};
string colName = ...
if(!allowedColumns.Contains(colName)) colName = allowedColumns[0]; // DENIED!
```

Once you have white-listed the column against expected values, you now know that the value is not `"] where 1=1 drop table Users drop table Customers --"`

However! the search value should be parameterised, i.e.

```
`... LIKE @searchValue`
```

where the `searchValue` parameter is given the value `"%" + something.Text + "%"`

Comment: @Marc thank you for the advice. **never** required means there is no need at all to validate the above examples?

Comment: @RUiHAO That is correct; it is *never* required... when using parameterisation.

Comment: @Andrew i see. so can i assume that the above functions and statements are fairly safe from SQL injection?

Comment: @RUiHAO **No**... they are extremely vulnerable, because they are not using parameterisation.

Comment: @RUiHAO nonononononono that isn't what I said; examples 3 and 4 are **completely unsafe**. My point: validation is not the answer; parameterisation is.

Comment: @MarcGravell okay. from the code example you gave, is it okay if I alter my INSERT statement to the example you gave?

Comment: @RUiHAO with `@username` / `.Parameters` etc? yes, that is safe

Comment: @MarcGravell how do I run the `cmd.CommantText` that stores the SQL INSERT query?

Comment: @RUiHAO same as usual: ExecuteNonQuery, or ExecuteScalar, or ExecuteReader (depending on what the command returns)

Comment: @MarcGravell I have changed my code to what you've taught me. Now I need to execute the statement so that the values of the textbox will be input to my database. I am unsure of how to execute the statement as my previous INSERT statement is stored inside a string variable, and this time it is only a cmd command.

Comment: @RUiHAO you add parameters via the command's `.Parameters` collection. Simply add a parameter (and a corresponding value) for everything you need. There are also tools to simplify this further if you need, like "dapper-dot-net", which removes the need to mess with the command or parameters *at all*.

Comment: @MarcGravell I have successfully updated my table using the parameters. Thank you

Comment: +1, Excellent explanation. By this I come to know how we have to explain a solution to others.

Answer (score 2):

Create SqlCommand and pass the data as SqlParameter will do the task for you

MSDN : [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

```
private static void UpdateDemographics(Int32 customerID,
    string demoXml, string connectionString)
{
    // Update the demographics for a store, which is stored 
    // in an xml column. 
    string commandText = "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics "
        + "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

        // Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics.
        // SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. how do I pass the data as an SqlParameter? examples or sites would be appreciated.

Comment: @RUiHAO  -  like this command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);  which is already there in the code example

Answer (score 1):

The very easiest way is inputting the parameters into the sql command instead of passing it directly. The .net and Sql will take care of the data types passed, if you pass the values through parameters.

For Example see the following:

```
SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * From [UserData] where ColumnValue like  @RowValue";
SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowValue","% ActualRowValue %");
```

You can add the parameters using the markup. Refer to the [asp:SqlDataSource select command with parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx)

Comment: you can't parameterise the column

Comment: that actually isn't parameterised; it is looking for something containing the **literal** `' @RowValue '` - which is very different to something that contains the value from the *parameter* `@RowValue`. Should be `like '%' + @RowValue + '%'`

Comment: @MarcGravell, thankyou actually in some confusious moode I wrote like that.