# Is it possible to replace " (double quotes) with a white space in a string?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

At some point of execusion of my project, the input to the database is in the format:

> Buy Requirement of "xxxxxx & xxxxxx" through mycompany.com

It results in an incorrect SQL syntax error. I need to replace `"` with white space. I  searched in google but no helpful suggestions were there.

How to replace `"` with whitespace?

```vb
Dim str As String
str="Buy Requirement of "Telemarketing & ERP Software" through IndiaMART.com"
' TODO: perform replace 

' result
str = "Buy Requirement of Telemarketing & ERP Software through IndiaMART.com"
```

Comment: You need to use SQL patamerets: [Preventing SQL Injection on ASP.NET Web Application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8411968/7586). It is safe (your code **already has** a security bug), and handles escaping and formatting for all data types automatically for you.

Comment: but how to replace " with white space.. the question still remains

Comment: @SujithKarivelil - That's the wrong question: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/7586). (although the deleted answer had it: `str.Replace("""", "")`)

Comment: the deleted answer is not for the question that's why it was deleted. in question they ask to replace "(only one double quotes ) but str.Replace("""", "")) will not useful in this situation str.Replace("""", "")) will replace only a pair of double quotes

Comment: @Kobi that replace wouldn't work...

Comment: is it possible to replace " ?

Comment: @ Mr CoDeXeR - that answer will not meet the requirement c my comment for the answer

Comment: @SujithKarivelil - Seems to be working: http://ideone.com/x8VEbe , but again, that is besides the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understand what you are asking now...

Here, this is what you want to be using: `teststring.Replace(""""c, "")`

If you really want to use Linq and extension methods, then use this: `New String(teststring.Where(Function(c) Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) OrElse Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray())`.

But that's just making things complicated for no reason.

Comment: still remains one quote in the string

Comment: I thought you wanted to replace only one double quote?

Comment: each single double quote (")

Comment: am having  following code but it removes space also `Dim input As String = InputBox("ENTER")
        Dim output As String = New String((From c As Char In input Select c Where Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray())`
        MsgBox(output)

Comment: Ok, try something like this: `MyString.Select(Function(c) Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) orelse Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))`

Comment: Amended code again. You need to use the overload of replace that accepts a `char` argument.

Comment: result in error : Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'. near  `orelse`

Comment: Have a look at my answer please. I amended again since I finally understand what you were after.

Comment: Oops, my bad, the extension method should have been `Select`. This is what you want: `New String(teststring.Where(Function(c) Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) OrElse Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray())`