# C# How can I prevent SQL Injection with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

I have a page that will generate an AuthKey for my web-app. I am using an Access Database database (just to try it locally, later on I will step to SQL Server). In my code-behind I am using C# as my writing language.

This is my code:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
OleDBCommand cmd = new OleDBCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into AuthKeys (AuthKey, User_Assign,locatedAt) values(@AuthKey, @idstr, 'Dashboard')";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AuthKey", OleDbTypes.<sometype>).Value = AuthKey;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idstr", OleDbTypes.<sometype>).Value = idstr;
```

the idstr == the userName
the AuthKey == code generated key (GUID)
But as I noticed, this application is very vulnerable for SQL Injection. So my question is: how can I prevent SQL Injection?

**EDIT**: My question is related to this forum post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/94608549-6fee-4c01-82ae-601ed7c20327/getting-errors-with-insert-into?forum=sqlnetfx#e933c92b-8d0a-4b40-906f-2d335b30b6d4

Comment: No, it is **not** vulnerable since you _already_ use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: I don't see any code that performs an action based on a URL so as it stands it's not possible to SQL inject

Comment: Without explanation why you believe "this application is very vulnerable for SQL Injection" this is not really reasonable question.

Comment: @SonerGönül but I managed to Inject (unauthorized) authkeys in my database table, which was very easy. With another application

Comment: So how should you validate them? @HugoWoesthuis

Comment: @HugoWoesthuis What do you mean by _unauthorized_ exactly? Are you _really_ sure you know what is SQL Injection means?

Comment: Please, show the code that you injected data with

Comment: This was an comment in another forum "Never - and I mean NEVER - inject user input to the SQL string. That opens your application for SQL injection."

Comment: If you never put any user input into your DB, you generally simply won't have any data in your DB. You're not putting any user info in your SQL _string_; you're putting it in parameters as you're supposed to. No Bobby Tables here.

Comment: Is is really vulnerable ? If so please explain how. I dont even see any dynamic variables in the code snippet.

Comment: You have the problem with authorization, not the sql injection.

Comment: That article shows a user putting actual user info into the string. You don't do that. Using parameters already ensures injection safety since they get escaped where needed.

Comment: Please check this [link]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411968/preventing-sql-injection-on-asp-net-web-application?rq=1

Comment: Please also check this link to get any idea of what SQL injection _really_ is: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: that post is saying this  is the right way to **prevent** SQL  injection. Not that this will be affected by SQL injection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But as I noticed, this application is very vulnerable for SQL Injection.

No, it is not. You cannot tamper with the actual SQL statement since you use parameters already. There is no SQL injection vulnerability in your code.

Comment: I believe you mean 'tamper' ;)

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between unauthorized injection of code that executes in the script to perform unwanted behavior in your SQL statements and simply inserting data into the table that you don't want.

In this case, you'd likely be wanting something more on the validation side of things to prevent these unwanted record entries.

Answer (score 1):

Quite the contrary, this approach (using prepared statements and parameterized queries) is the only sensible and reliable way of avoiding SQL injectons.

Mind you, if you're doing weird SQL trickery on the back end (like concatenating parameter values to get "dynamic SQL"-like behavior), you can still be bitten by SQL injection.